# setState called during build in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a flutter app and all I want to do here is change bool isSwitched to either true or false when the user changes the LiteRollingSwitch. (I used this https://pub.dev/packages/lite_rolling_switch#-readme-tab- library). Inside of onchage method, if I create "setstate " it gives me an errorlike this below.
[image]

but I need to change the isSwitched state to either true or false depends on the user's choice; it allows a user to blur the image or unblur the image. Anyone has and idea to solve this issue??

```
class UploadPhoto extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _UploadPhotoState createState() => _UploadPhotoState();
    }

class _UploadPhotoState extends State<UploadPhoto> {
  bool isSwitched = false;
  File _image;

  // select image via either folder of camera
  Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile image =
        await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
  }

  Future getImageFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(...),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: _image != null
                            ? Center(
                                    Transform.scale(
                                  scale: 0.8,
                                  child: LiteRollingSwitch(
                                    value: isSwitched,
                                    textOn: 'On',
                                    textOff: 'Off',
                                    colorOn: Hexcolor("#8CC63E"),
                                    colorOff: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    iconOn: Icons.done,
                                    iconOff: Icons.remove_circle_outline,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
//                                      isSwitched = value;
                                      setState(() {
                                        isSwitched = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Good news*: it's not your fault.

*Bad news*: You have to modify their code or wait till they change it.

I created a pull request on github [here](https://github.com/cgustav/lite_rolling_switch/pull/5). However they don't seem to respond to issues so you might be better off changing their code.

So meanwhile if you want to use this package you should change the code inside **lite_rolling_switch.dart** (either by going to ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/lite_rolling_switch-0.1.1/lib/lite_rolling_switch.dart or you can Ctrl + left click on the class LiteRollingSwitch in your file) to the following:

```
library lite_rolling_switch;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:math';

/// Customable and attractive Switch button.
/// Currently, you can't change the widget
/// width and height properties.
///
/// As well as the classical Switch Widget
/// from flutter material, the following
/// arguments are required:
///
/// * [value] determines whether this switch is on or off.
/// * [onChanged] is called when the user toggles the switch on or off.
///
/// If you don't set these arguments you would
/// experiment errors related to animationController
/// states or any other undesirable behavior, please
/// don't forget to set them.
///
class LiteRollingSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final bool value;
  @required
  final Function(bool) onChanged;
  final String textOff;
  final String textOn;
  final Color colorOn;
  final Color colorOff;
  final double textSize;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final IconData iconOn;
  final IconData iconOff;
  final Function onTap;
  final Function onDoubleTap;
  final Function onSwipe;

  LiteRollingSwitch(
      {this.value = false,
      this.textOff = "Off",
      this.textOn = "On",
      this.textSize = 14.0,
      this.colorOn = Colors.green,
      this.colorOff = Colors.red,
      this.iconOff = Icons.flag,
      this.iconOn = Icons.check,
      this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      this.onTap,
      this.onDoubleTap,
      this.onSwipe,
      this.onChanged});

  @override
  _RollingSwitchState createState() => _RollingSwitchState();
}

class _RollingSwitchState extends State<LiteRollingSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  double value = 0.0;

  bool turnState;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        lowerBound: 0.0,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        duration: widget.animationDuration);
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        value = animation.value;
      });
    });
    turnState = widget.value;
    if (turnState) {
      animationController.animateTo(1, duration: Duration(seconds: 0));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color transitionColor = Color.lerp(widget.colorOff, widget.colorOn, value);

    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        _action();
        if (widget.onDoubleTap != null) widget.onDoubleTap();
      },
      onTap: () {
        _action();
        if (widget.onTap != null) widget.onTap();
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        _action();
        if (widget.onSwipe != null) widget.onSwipe();
        //widget.onSwipe();
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        width: 130,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: transitionColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(10 * value, 0), //original
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: (1 - value).clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.textOff,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: widget.textSize),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(10 * (1 - value), 0), //original
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: value.clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(/*top: 10,*/ left: 5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  height: 40,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.textOn,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: widget.textSize),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(80 * value, 0),
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: lerpDouble(0, 2 * pi, value),
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: Opacity(
                          opacity: (1 - value).clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            widget.iconOff,
                            size: 25,
                            color: transitionColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                          child: Opacity(
                              opacity: value.clamp(0.0, 1.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                widget.iconOn,
                                size: 21,
                                color: transitionColor,
                              ))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _action() {
    _determine(changeState: true);
  }

  _determine({bool changeState = false}) {
    setState(() {
      if (changeState) turnState = !turnState;
      (turnState)
          ? animationController.forward()
          : animationController.reverse();

      widget.onChanged(turnState);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... It's working, thank you so much for figuring this out...